# .NET 6.0 Visual Studio 2022 Aws Lambda Function

Tags: .net, aws

como estan? Estoy intentando hacer un Deploy a AWS Lambda de mi proyecto de API, me hace el deploy correctamente pero al tratar de consumir una API mediante la URL que me da AWS me arroja el siguiente error:

{"message": "Internal server error"}

Les dejo mi codigo de configuracion:

serverless.template:

```
    {
  "AWSTemplateFormatVersion" : "2010-09-09",
  "Transform" : "AWS::Serverless-2016-10-31",
  "Description" : "Starting template for an AWS Serverless Application.",
  "Parameters" : {
  },
  "Resources" : {
    "DefaultFunction" : {
      "Type" : "AWS::Serverless::Function",
      "Properties": {
        "Handler": "RtvcApi::RtvcApi.LambdaEntryPoint::FunctionHandlerAsync",
        "Runtime": "dotnet6",
        "CodeUri": "",
        "Description": "Default function",
        "MemorySize": 256,
        "Timeout": 30,
        "Role": null,
        "Policies": [ "AWSLambda_FullAccess" ],
        "Events": {
          "ProxyResource": {
            "Type": "Api",
            "Properties": {
              "Path": "/{proxy+}",
              "Method": "ANY"
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "Outputs" : {
    "ApiURL" : {
        "Description" : "API endpoint URL for Prod environment",
        "Value" : { "Fn::Sub" : "https://${ServerlessRestApi}.execute-api.${AWS::Region}.amazonaws.com/Prod/" }
    }
  }
}
```

aws-lambda-tools-defaults.json

```
{
    "Information" : [
        "This file provides default values for the deployment wizard inside Visual Studio and the AWS Lambda commands added to the .NET Core CLI.",
        "To learn more about the Lambda commands with the .NET Core CLI execute the following command at the command line in the project root directory.",
        "dotnet lambda help",
        "All the command line options for the Lambda command can be specified in this file."
    ],
    "profile"     : "StoreSysAWS",
    "region"      : "us-east-1",
    "configuration" : "Release",
    "function-runtime" : "dotnet6",
    "framework"        : "net6.0",
    "template"         : "serverless.template",
    "template-parameters" : "",
    "s3-prefix"           : "CoreAPI/",
    "s3-bucket"           : "rtvapibucket",
    "stack-name"          : "CoreAPIStack"
}
```

LambdaEntryPoint.cs

```
using Amazon.Lambda.AspNetCoreServer;

namespace RtvcApi;

public class LambdaEntryPoint : APIGatewayProxyFunction
{
    protected override void Init(IWebHostBuilder builder)
    {
        builder
            .UseContentRoot(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())
            .UseStartup<Program>()
            .UseLambdaServer();
    }
}
```

Program.cs

```
using CleanArchitecture.Identity;
using Infrastructure.EntityFramework;
using RtvcApi;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory());
        var app = CreateHostBuilder(args).Build();
        app.Run();

    }

    public static IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder(string[] args)
    {
        IConfigurationRoot configuration = new ConfigurationBuilder()
           .SetBasePath(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())
           .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", optional: false, reloadOnChange: true)
           .Build();

        return Host.CreateDefaultBuilder()
            .ConfigureWebHostDefaults(
            webBuilder =>
            webBuilder
            .UseStartup<Startup>())
            .ConfigureServices((context, services) =>
            {
                services.AddControllers();
                services.AddApplicationServices();
                services.AddAuthentication();
                services.AddCors(options =>
                {
                    options.AddPolicy("CorsPolicy", builder =>
                    builder
                    .AllowAnyOrigin()
                    .AllowAnyHeader()
                    .AllowAnyMethod()
                    );
                });
                services.AddEndpointsApiExplorer();
                services.AddSwaggerGen();
                services.AddInfrastructureServices(configuration);
                services.ConfigureAuthenticationServices(configuration);
                services.AddAuthorization();
            });
    }
}
```

Startup.cs

```
using RtvcApi.Middlewares;

namespace RtvcApi;

public class Startup
{
    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
    {
        if (env.IsDevelopment()) 
        {
            app.UseSwagger();
            app.UseSwaggerUI();
        }

        
        app.UseCors("CorsPolicy");
        app.UseRouting();
        app.UseMiddleware<ExceptionMiddleware>();
        app.UseAuthorization();
        app.UseAuthentication();
        app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
        {
            endpoints.MapControllers();
            endpoints.MapGet("/test", async context =>
            {
                await context.Response.WriteAsync("va...");
            });
        });
    }
}
```

Intente de muchas formas para subir y publicar la API, en todas me las sube bien pero me tira siempre el mismo error.

Ejemplos de links en los que intente:

https://nodogmablog.bryanhogan.net/2022/10/simple-dependency-injection-for-net-lambda-functions/

https://github.com/aws/aws-lambda-dotnet/discussions/1370

https://nodogmablog.bryanhogan.net/2022/01/net-6-web-api-in-a-container-in-a-lambda/

https://aws.amazon.com/es/blogs/compute/introducing-the-net-6-runtime-for-aws-lambda/

Desde ya muchas gracias, espero puedan ayudarme ! Saludos

Comment: Si has recibido un Internal Server Error, revisa los logs de CloudWatch, ya que es posible que ahí te encuentres con una excepción al ejecutar la lambda. La excepción puede ser porque a tu lambda le falten dependencias, algún recurso de AWS que es inaccesible por el rol de la lambda o por infinidad de motivos ... pero sin esa información vas a ir dando palos de ciego

Comment: Hola @eferion buen dia, gracias por responder, el error que me tira es el siguiente:

---> System.InvalidOperationException: A public method named 'ConfigureProduction' or 'Configure' could not be found in the 'Program' type.

realmente estuve siguiendo los pasos de los tutoriales, de hecho me compre un curso para aws amazon developer, pero no puedo realmente subir mi aplicacion y no se cual es el problema! Gracias por responder.

Comment: El error parece claro y conciso, te está buscando el método `Configure` en la clase `Program` ... tu lo tienes definido en la clase `Startup`. Cambia el método de sitio (o no se si habrá alguna forma de indicar la ubicación real del método)

Comment: Bien, gracias @eferion ya volvi a poner la clase Startup en vez la de program en mi .UseStartup de "LambdaEntryPoint.cs", ahora al hacer el deploy me arroja otro error que me tiraba antes que es:

---> System.InvalidOperationException: Unable to find the required services. Please add all the required services by calling 'IServiceCollection.AddAuthorization' in the application startup code.

Esa configuracion la tengo en Program  que levanta el IServiceCollection, pero no se como ponerla en el Startup Configure, no se si es por ahi el error o por donde viene.
Gracias y perdon por molestar!

Comment: Ese error parece depender de las librerías que estás usando para "levantar" la API. Lo siento pero ahí no te puedo ayudar